# ActionScript3: show and hide symbol every 5 frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, symbols

I have a simple straight line on my stage in Flash and I want it to come up and dissapear again every 5 frames for example.

Is this possible with Action Script 3?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myLine:MovieClip;
var count:int = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
{
    count ++;
    if(count == 5)
    {
        myLine.visible = false;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        myLine.visible = true;
    }
}
```